# Rails 3: Removing a Gem from project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently using devise for my authentication solution however I really don't like it and want to use authlogic instead.

How can i remove the Devise gem from my project completely so i can then add the authlogic gem safely?

Comment: i respect your decision, but bear in mind that most Rails developers(including me), reckon devise as a much superior choice.

Comment: That's fair enough, I can see how its so much better and more powerful with more features, I just prefer the simplicity of authlogic as my system is just a prototype. I want to make changes to the controllers for the user and that's just messy in devsie.

Answer (score 10):

You can remove the Devise gem from your Gemfile and then run `bundle install`. The gem should then be removed.

To be safe, you can also run the following:

`gem uninstall gem_name` from the command line.

Answer (score 9):

McStretch's advice is incomplete.

You will need to:

- Remove the gem from your `Gemfile`
- Remove the `devise_for` call in your `config/routes.rb` file
- Remove the `devise` call from your `app/models/user.rb` file
- Delete `config/initializers/devise.rb`
- Remove any custom overrides for devise's controllers or views that you may have in `app/controllers` or `app/views` respectively.

Comment: I figured he already removed Devise-specific code given "How can i remove the Devise gem".